# 12 hperthread used evenly with 7 processes in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a task `get_geotif_by_band(band_number):...`.

Now my multiprocessing code is as follow:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(12) as p:
        p.map(get_geotif_by_band, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

My cpu has 6 cores and 12 Logical processors.

Now I expect 7 logical processor to be fully used other being used normally by other task.

But I see all the processors are used equally (evenly).

[image]

How can we explain this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you need to have in order to occupy 7 threads

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def function(source_data):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=7) as executor:
        executor.map(function, source_data)
```

Comment: Okay, but what happens when it was 12 instead of 7, was task being shared across logical processors?

Comment: While I can not imagine why there is a load of 12 threads, if you list of 7 elements. Write to me if my answer helped you

Comment: It did not help me because I am trying to understand how 7 task is executed evenly on 12 logical processors.